# Download a file which does not exists in project directory in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my project i just wanted to implement upload and download features. I have done upload functionality with AngularJS and Node.js. But here the problem is to upload a file(.pdf, all image formats) into somewhere in the system. Say for example, my project is located in D drive. Though i have to upload a file into C drive or some other drive in my computer and i have done it successfully. But when i try to read the file location from Node.js and pass the path to angular, everything is ok and file is downloaded in the browser. when i try to open a downloaded file it sends back a response - fatal error/ nothing to show. I have tried with blob only when i send a filestream instead a path to Angular.

The code is as follows

```
       var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
       var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
       window.open(fileURL);
```

where data is a file stream response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

not my code but try this to save a BLOB:

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-download.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cw7w5/

If you want to force the download of a linked file you could use the HTML5 `a` option `download` 
`<a download="filename_for_download" href="path/to/the/file"> Clicking o will force a download</a>`
Some more information: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download?hl=en
keep the (not existing) support of older browsers in mind

One Note: Your upload process ("to upload a file into C drive or some other drive in my computer") sounds like it may be improved or rethought.